# VB .Net, SQL Server 2012 Express database connection

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2012 Express database located in `DATA` folder but I get the error "instance error". I've tried several connection strings but seems that this one is ok because when I modify it intentionally wrong, different error is returned (typical one),

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server...

Code:

```
Public SQLConn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;database=JaumeDB;Trusted_Connection=Yes;connection timeout=30"}

Public SQLCommand As SqlCommand

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

                    If isConnectedToSQL() Then
                        MsgBox("cool!!")
                    End If

                End Sub

Public Function isConnectedToSQL() As Boolean

                    Try
                        SQLConn.Open()

                        SQLConn.Close()

                        Return True

                    Catch ex As Exception

                        MsgBox(ex.Message)

                        Return False

                    End Try

                End Function
```

Comment: Did you enable the TCP/IP Client Protocol in the Sql Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: yes, I already have TCP/IP protocol enabled

Comment: have your checked the SQLEXPRESS service? is it started?

Comment: yes, service is started. I just restarted it but problem persist.

Comment: what about this one for your connection string: `Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=JaumeDB;Integrated Security=True` ?

Comment: also are you able to connect with the current user(windows) to SQLEXPRESS instance? (windows mode)

Comment: @Farhęg I am prety sure that already tested this connection string... however, I did so many changes and I tried it again... it works!! please post it as an answer and I apreciate so much your help

Comment: You are welcome bro, of course, I will, just a minute...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something that you need to check i.e:

1. check for the `TCP/IP` Client Protocol in the `Sql Server Configuration Manager` is it enabled?
2. check the services and see is `SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS)` service started?
3. check if you can login to `SQLEXPRESS` instance in windows mode with your current user(windows)?
4. try with this connection string(change the database to initial catalog):

`Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=JaumeDB;Integrated Security=True`

5. etc.
   Hope these be helpful.